# .htacces redirect not working non-www url to www url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have tried below code to redirect non www to www url in wordpresss but its not working .

Please check below code is right one?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.ie[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.ie/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite installed? Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Why isn't is working? Do you recieve some error messages?

Comment: @KoenHollander 500 internal server error

Comment: If you got 500 internal server error - check the `error.log` and add the relevant error (from the logs) to the question (**don't add it as a comment**)

Answer (score 1):

The proper .htaccess rule should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Keep in mind that Wordpress has own rewrite rules installed in .htaccess file, do not remove them (they are placed between comments lines `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`)

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual at https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/non-www/

The correct code is

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Otherwise there may be a other problem that you can reprocedure from the error logs